# How to mock a function decorator in Flask?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, python-decorators, python-mock

I have a file named `myviews.py` that lives under a directory named `views`, which in turn in under a directory named `src` containing some views that looks like so:

```
from utils import verify_refresh_token
fetch_views = Blueprint('foo', __name, url_prefix='bar')

@fetchviews.route('baz', methods=['GET'])
@verify_refresh_token
def process_request():
    return 'test'
```

Within `utils.py`, I have the verify_refresh_token function that more or less does:

```
def verify_refresh_token(func):
   @wraps(func)
   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
   return wrapper
```

Within my test file, I have something like:

```
from src.main import app
....
def setUp(self):
   with mock.patch('src.views.myviews.verify_refresh_token') as mock_verify_token:
      self.test_app = app.test_client(self)

def test_stuff(self):
   self.tester.post('bar/baz', data={})
```

Regardless of what I patch (changing `src.views.myviews.verify_refresh_token` to `src.utils.verify_refresh_token`, etc) the decorator still gets called and crashes my app. What is the correct way to handle mocking out this decorator? The views are added to `main.py` like so:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
from views.myviews import fetchviews
app.register_blueprint(fetchviews)
```

Comment: The correct way is to mock the behavior *inside* the decorator, because decorators are called when the function is defined, not when it is executed. I'm assuming there's something inside `verify_refresh_token` that verifies some token, which you didn't include in your post. Just mock that instead.

Comment: @univerio that did the trick! I had to change the mocks around. Thanks!

Comment: @ClicquotTheDog and why didn't you post your solution?